# PivotTable Calculated Item IF Statement Issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have two columns of data in a pivot table but one of the columns is only partially populated. I've been able to use 'Calculated Item' to add a third column that will calculate the difference between both columns, but I'd like an IF statement that ensures the 'difference' column remains blank when the partially populated column is blank.

[image: Image showing attempted formula and result.]

I've tested the logic outside of the pivot table in standard cells and this works fine. When applying the same IF logic to a formula in 'Calculated Item' however, it simply defaults to the 'else' and calculates difference no matter what. I wondered if anybody had any advice for me for this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Cool question. Your test is failing because your CategoryB field isn't actually null. You can get around the difficulty of null vs blank vs 0 etc by writing the condition differently. Try `=IF(CategoryA-CategoryB=CategoryA,"n/a",CategoryA-CategoryB)` and that'll work. (You could also figure out what the correct test against CategoryB would be, if you prefer a less hacky solution)

Comment: Interestingly, the solution provided works only if I replace n/a with a numerical string - text returns #VALUE! instead. I assumed this may have been because of n/a being seen as n divided by a but trying any text string at all returns the issue, but any numerical string does not. I wonder if this is a limitation of 'calculated item'? 

I used the ISBLANK function and it appears you are indeed correct that the CategoryB field isn't actually blank - now I just need to work out the correct test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by building upon Alex M's advice.

`=IF(CategoryA-CategoryB=CategoryA,"n/a",CategoryA-CategoryB)` returned #VALUE! error using a text string when the IF condition was met, so selecting the pivot table option 'For error values show: n/a' functions as a crude workaround that achieves the desired result.

Comment: That's actually fairly humorous that your DESIRED result was to display a text string 'n/a' but instead you were getting a #VALUE error.
Good job using `ISBLANK` etc tests to work this out for yourself.